# iOS custom headset buttons controllers in native application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I also developed functionality for an application, I want to use the keys headphone. With the Volume Up and Volume Down buttons change the menu in the headphones, I want the menu selection to be made with the MUTE button. About this event can help me?

Note: SDK 7 and 7+

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Volume/Mute level with the following code, this worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
    name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
    object:nil];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume =
    [[[notification userInfo]
      objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
 floatValue];

// Do stuff with volume
}
```